# 3rd party library complain about MAXPATHLEN not declared in one project but not on other project

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-14.04, dtn

***OS  : Ubuntu 14.04

SDK : Qt 5.5

library : "ion.h"  [ I have built ion-dtn 3rd party library from source and it has ion.h file which I am using in my 2 projects ]***

I am using ion.h in my 2 projects in same development system. Both projects are based on Qt. On including ion.h  One project runs without any compilation error , other complains  about MAXPATHLEN.

```
/usr/local/include/ion.h:60: error: 'MAXPATHLEN' was not declared in this scope
  char pathName[MAXPATHLEN + 1];.
```

On project where it's running fine , I  can click on ion.h  and  found `MAXPATHLEN` is highlighted with blue, obviously means qt can find it and on clicking "follow under symbol"  I found its declared in param.h under sys directory.

I cant do the same in my other project. On clicking ion.h `MAXPATHLEN` is in black colour and couldnt able to find param.h when I click follow under symbol.

I have compared and my .pro files are same in both projects. Can soemone please guide me what I am doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MAXPATHLEN` is declared in `<sys/param.h>`. One project must include it (or another header file including it...like `<QDir>` for instance, it's hard to tell) while the other does not.

Simply include `<sys/param.h>` before you include `ion.h` yourself to solve the problem.

If you really want to figure out who's including this file and then identify why `MAXPATHLEN` is defined in one project, there are compiler options for that (like `/showIncludes` for g++).

Comment: Thanks jpo38. I have include <sys/param.h> and it solved problem. May be in project where its working fine , thsi library is already included by some other library.